# jasmine mock value an service value are different

Tags: angular, testing, post, jasmine, httpclient

I'm testing my HttpClient post method with jasmine:
but it's in error because the return value of my business logic method is an Empty array, but if I run the same method from the angular component the value is a filled array equal my mock data.

```
it('should call POST /MonitoraggioWS/rs/public/getListaCanaliWSR and return all Channels', () => {
    let actualData = {};
    let filter: IChannelFilter = {channelCode:'', resourceId:'', resourceType:'QUEUE'};
    service.getAllChannels(filter).subscribe(data => actualData = data);

    backend.expectOne((req: HttpRequest<any>) => {
      return req.url === `/MonitoraggioWS/rs/public/getListaCanaliWSR` && req.method === 'POST'
    }, 'Load all channels from /MonitoraggioWS/rs/public/getListaCanaliWSR').flush(channels);

    expect(actualData).toEqual(channels);
  });
```

the service is:

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post<IChannel[]>(`/MonitoraggioWS/rs/public/getListaCanaliWSR`, JSON.stringify(filter),{headers: headers}).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        let channelList: IChannel[] = [];
        if(data && data.channelAdapterList){
          data.channelAdapterList.forEach(data =>{
            channelList.push({
              lastUpdateTimestamp: data.lastUpdateTimestamp,lastUpdateUser: data.lastUpdateUser, external: data.external,
              headerExit: data.headerExit, id: data.channelCode, description: data.description, channelCode: data.channelCode,
              headerFormat: data.headerFormat, resourceId: data.resourceId, resourceType: data.resourceType, saviour: data.saviour,
              version: data.version, organizationLevelTwoDefinition: data.organizationLevelTwoDefinition,
              organizationLevelOneDefinition: data.organizationLevelTwoDefinition, mappingOid: data.mappingOid, key: null,
            });
          });
        }
        return channelList;
      }), catchError( error => {
        return throwError( 'MonitoringAPI Something went wrong! '+ error);
      })
    );
  }
```

My test is in failure because actualDate (the return value of my business method is an Array []), but if I run the method from angular component the Array is filled with the same values of my mock, could be possible that the issue is my business logic service?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your entire question but I believe you are asserting at a wrong time.

```
it('should call POST /MonitoraggioWS/rs/public/getListaCanaliWSR and return all Channels', 
// add this done argument so we can tell Jasmine when we are done with our assertions
(done) => {
    let actualData = {};
    let filter: IChannelFilter = {channelCode:'', resourceId:'', resourceType:'QUEUE'};
    service.getAllChannels(filter).subscribe(data => { 
            console.log(data); // see the console to make sure it is the mock
            actualData = data; // assign actualData to the mock data
            expect(actualData).toEqual(channels); // do your assertion here
            done(); // call done to let Jasmine know we are done with our assertions.
    });

    backend.expectOne((req: HttpRequest<any>) => {
      return req.url === `/MonitoraggioWS/rs/public/getListaCanaliWSR` && req.method === 'POST'
    }, 'Load all channels from /MonitoraggioWS/rs/public/getListaCanaliWSR').flush(channels);

    // expect(actualData).toEqual(channels); // doing the assertion here is too early
  });
```

Comment: console.log(data);  here the array is empty 
error:

 expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 30
    + Received  +  1